# How to pass a struts2 text field's value as a parameter in href?

Tags: java, struts2

I have a text field and a link(). I need to pass my text field's value to a action class. In my action class, I need to get text field's value as a parameter(request.getParameter()). In my jsp page I declared such as,

```
<s:textfield name="input" value="1" label="Qty"/>
<s:a href="OrderReview?&input=/*text field value as a parameter*/">Buy</s:a>
```

I need to get text field's value in my action class such as,

```
request.getParameter("input");
```

Is this possible? If it is how can I do this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call a javascript function on anchor click and get textfield's value and set href of anchor.

As,

```
<s:textfield id="input" name="input" value="1" label="Qty"/>
<s:a href="OrderReview?&input=" onclick="getInputValue(this);">Buy</s:a>

function getInputValue(obj){
    var inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;
    if(obj.href.indexOf(inputValue) == -1){
        obj.href += inputValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: It;s working now.. not this.href, It should be obj.href. Thanks

Comment: Ohhh sorry, i just forgot in hurry that i have taken variable as obj not this. :)

Comment: first click works, but second just appends to the existing value.